# How to use Angular parameter with Laravel blade

Tags: php, jquery, angular, laravel

How can i use the parameter from Angular in Laravel blade?

I try this code:

```
 <?php echo \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimeStamp(strtotime(@{{user.lastseen}})->diffForHumans() ?>
```

and

```
{{\Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimestamp(strtotime(@{{user.lastseen}}))}}
```

But i got an Error any idea?

Comment: Php generate the HTML code first, then the client browser get the HTML content and rendered it where js execute. So the php code is execute on the server, while the js code is execute on the clinet. So the php function cannot get the angular variable's value on the server side.

Comment: Try the `@verbatim` blade.

Comment: @KrisRoofe: ok i got it thank you

Comment: @aldrin27 what is @verbatim??

Comment: You can see that in the laravel blades section.

Answer (score 1):

By default AngularJS and Blade conflict with the way variables are called. Both use a double curly bracket `{{ var }}` syntax. There are a few workarounds such as changing Angular’s or Blade’s delimiters but an easier method is available.

Inside blade prefix Angular echo variables with the at “@“ symbol. Here is an example:

```
$var = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimestamp(strtotime(@{{user.lastseen}}));

@{{ $var }}
```

This will prevent blade from parsing it but will be correct when sent to the browser.

Comment: You can escape data in blade like :- {!! $var !!}

Comment: Not error $var but error your first script  $var = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimestamp(strtotime(@{{user.lastseen}}));